# Is there a way to use pytest.raises in pytest-bdd "When" steps?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-bdd

I would like to define a scenario as follows:

```gherkin
Scenario: An erroneous operation
  Given some data
  And some more data
  When I perform an operation
  Then an exception is raised
```

Is there a good way to do this so that the `when` step isn't actually called until a `pytest.raises` context manager can be constructed for it? I could use a callable fixture, but that's going to pollute all other uses of the `"I perform an operation"` step.

Comment: Could you clarify the question please ? You can always just wrap your operation in this way in your relevant test: 
``` 
with pytest.raises(Exception):
        perform_operation(data, more_data)
```

Comment: @YassineElBouchaibi If the `When` step is defined generically, then `I perform an operation` should be unaware of whether it's going to succeed or fail. The question of whether an error _should occur_ is only known in the `Then` step -- at which point the `When` step is already executed.

Is there a way to have `pytest-bdd` "consume" the `When` step as part of the `Then` step, so that `When` is only called in the context of `Then`?

Comment: It sounds like you might be overcomplicating this in a way that will hurt test reliability and code maintainability? Tests should be deterministic (set a seed to deal with randomness). So you should know the expected outcome of each test case at dev time. Then write two tests: one test contains "ok" test cases, the other contains "bad" and makes use of the context manager. You could pass the expected outcome as a part of the parameterization of the test case (and add an `if` statement in your test function) but that needlessly obfuscates the intent of the test.

Comment: This is not randomness, it's the structure of a BDD test. The `When` step should be generic, not aware of whether it'll succeed or fail; it's equivalent to a function call. The `Then` step specifies the state after the `When` step has been run.

The `When` step has no context for the `Then` step, so it can't special case ("if then_step expects failure, then use pytest.raises"). Similarly, the `Then` step doesn't control execution of the `When` step, so it can't wrap its execution conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood your question correctly, but aren't you trying to achieve something like this?

1. Before each `When` step we are checking if next `Then` step contains `"is raised"`.
2. If so, we mark this `When` step as "expected to fail".
3. During needed `When` step execution we check corresponding flag and use `pytest.raises` method to handle it.

For first two steps I use [pytest_bdd_before_step](https://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#hooks) hook and `request` fixture. And for 3rd I just define some function `handle_step` right in test module. Of course you should move it somewhere else. This function requires `step` (which is just some defined function with your code) and `request.node.step.expect_failure` to decide whether to use `pytest.raises` or not.

As an option you can use callable fixture (requesting `request` fixture) to store this function and avoid using `request.node.step.expect_failure` in such keywords.

Also you can add functionality to define allowed exceptions and so on.

**test_exception.py**

```
import pytest
from pytest_bdd import then, when, scenario


@scenario("exc.feature", "Test expecting correct exception")
def test_1():
    pass


def handle_step(step, expect_failure):
    if expect_failure:
        pytest.raises(Exception, step)
    else:
        step()


@when("I perform an operation")
def operation_calling_exception(request):
    def step():
        # some code that causes an exception
        print(1 / 0)
    handle_step(step, request.node.step.expect_failure)


@then('an exception is raised')
def ex_raised():
    pass
```

**exc.feature**

```
Feature: Target fixture
    Scenario: Test expecting correct exception
        When I perform an operation
        Then an exception is raised
```

**conftest.py**

```
def pytest_bdd_before_step(request, feature, scenario, step, step_func):
    # set default `expect_failure` for step
    step.expect_failure = False

    # make step available from request fixture
    request.node.step = step

    # Only for `When` keywords
    if step.keyword == "When":
        # get current step position in scenario
        step_position = scenario.steps.index(step)

        # get following `Then` step
        then_step = next((s for s in scenario.steps[step_position:] if s.keyword == "Then"), None)

        if "is raised" in then_step.name:
            step.expect_failure = True
```

Comment: I'll award the bounty here for effort, but unfortunately this level of hackery on the hook basically means: no, there's no way to do this [in an obvious, supported, and maintainable way]. 